# Haskell: for every even appearance in an array, concatenate an int to the final list

Tags: haskell

I'm currently trying to write a function that takes as arguments an Int and an array of Ints and for every even value in the array, it concatenates the Int to the final array.
So, something like this:
f 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6] = [1,2,3,3,4,3,5,6,3]

This is the code I imagined would work (I'm just beginning so sorry if it's bad):

```
f :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
f(x,[]) = []
f(x,y) 
    |even head(y) = (head(y) ++ [x] ++ f(x,drop 1 y)
    |otherwise = head(y) ++ f(x,(drop 1 y))
```

The error I'm getting is "Couldn't match expected type of 'Int' with actual type (a3, [[a3]])'. I understand the parameters types are mismatched, but I'm not sure how a proper syntax would look like here

Comment: You don't need to add `x` twice to the list.

Comment: I think when you said "array" you meant "list."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `(x, [])`, so that means the input type would be a tuple, so `f :: (Int, [Int]) -> [Int]`.

I would also use pattern matching instead of `head` and `tail`, so:

```
f :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
f _ [] = []
f x (y:ys)
    | even y = y : x : f x ys
    | otherwise = y : f x ys
```

You can also generalize the type signature, and work with an inner function to avoid passing the `x` each time:

```
f :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [a]
f x = go
  where go [] = []
        go (y:ys)
          | even y = y : x : go ys
          | otherwise = y : go ys
```

Comment: I'd rather `f x = concatMap go where go y | even y = [y,x] | otherwise = [y]`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! And (y:ys) returns a standalone int or an array of 1 element? Basically, 3 or [3]? The latter would make sense to me as the parameter is asking for a list

Comment: @DuduDudu: `(y:ys)` will patternmatch with a non-empty list, and will bind `y` to the first item of the list, and `ys` to a list of the remaining items.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at this would be using a right fold to insert the desired element after even numbers.

```
f :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
f x lst = foldr (\y i -> if even y then y:x:i else y:i) [] lst
```

Which we can simplify to:

```
f :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
f x = foldr (\y i -> if even y then y:x:i else y:i) []
```

Note that without specifying the type, the more general inferred type of `f` would be:

```
f :: (Foldable t, Integral a) => a -> t a -> [a]
```